# RSelenium extraCapabilities Error, can't open browser with profile

Tags: r, google-chrome, rselenium

I can succesfully open a chrome browser with below code

```
rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", chromever="102.0.5005.61", port = free_port() )
```

But when I try to open it with a **profile**, it opens 3 new windows with that profile and gives below error

```
cprof <- getChromeProfile(
    "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\",
    "Profile 1"
)

rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", chromever="102.0.5005.61", port = free_port(), extraCapabilities = cprof)
```

Error:

```
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-blahblah', ip: '192.168.0.70', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_333'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
     Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
     Detail: A new session could not be created.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
Check server log for further details.
```

I have even removed the needed browser extension from the profile, yet no luck. (So it doesn't work even though there's not any single browser extension.)
I have also closed all other chrome windows, but the problem persists.

What can I do right now ?
Is there a way to read the error log and understand why it happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Turn off below setup in chrome settings:
chrome://settings/system  >>
" Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed "

So, anyone having **SessionNotCreatedException** error can simply try turning off this setup, it may work as it happened in my case.